# Running/pausing child processes in C?

Tags: c, process, fork, blocking, waitpid

I'm running child processes in C and I want to pause and then run the same child process.  Not really sure how to describe my problem in a better way since I'm new at this but here's a shot.

So I know that you can run a process after another process exits by using `waitpid`.  But what if the process I'm waiting on doesn't exist at the creation of the process that does the waiting.  So in this case, I'm thinking of pausing the process that does the waiting and when the process that is waited is created and then finishes, it would call on the process that does the waiting to run again.  So how would you do this? Again, I'm not familiar with this, so I don't know if this is the proper way to do this.

edit: What I'm trying to do

I'm using child processes to run command via `execvp()` in parallel so if I have a sequence `sleep 1; sleep 1;`, the total sleep time will be 1 second.  However there are cases where I try to parallel `echo blah > file; cat < file;` in which case I'm assuming `cat` reads the file after `echo` inputs blah into file.  Therefore, I have to wait for `echo` to finish to do `cat`.  There are more specifics to this, but generally assume that for any command with an output to a file must be waited on by any command that reads the file later in the script.

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why do you even need a process to wait?

Comment: You get the PID when you call fork();  If you have not seen the Beej guide, I would suggest this: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fork.html  If you need to know when the child is done, then you will need some sort of IPC.

Comment: this is OS dependent, its not part of standard C, so you need to be a little more specific about what you are writing for.  I'm assuming *nix.

Comment: @KeithNicholas fork() is available on UNIX like systems only, so it's definitely that.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux: You can set an `alarm()` before you `waitpid()` so you can wakeup after a certain number of seconds and `waitpid()` should return EINTR so you would know the situation and can kill the misbehaving one. Another way would be to use a mutex and having a block like this in the waiting process:

```
if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) {
  sleep(some seconds);
  if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) {
    kill the process
  }
}
```

and the process that is monitored:

ENTRY-POINT:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
do_stuff();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any application (process) can only wait with `waitpid()` on its own direct children.  It can't wait on grandchildren or more distant descendants, and it can wait on neither siblings nor ancestors nor on unrelated processes.

If your application is single-threaded, you can't wait on a process that will be created after the `waitpid()` call starts because there is nothing to do the necessary `fork()` to create the child.

In a multi-threaded process, you could have one thread waiting for dying children and another thread could be creating the children.  For example, you could then have the `waitpid()` call in thread 1 start at time T0, then have thread 2 create a child at T1 (T1 > T0), and then the child dies at T2, and the `waitpid()` would pick up the corpse of the child at T3, even though the child was created after the `waitpid()` started.

Your higher level problem is probably not completely tractable.  You can't tell which processes are accessing a given file just by inspecting the command lines in a 'shell script'.  You can see those that probably are using it (because the file name appears on the command line); but there may be other processes that have the name hardwired into them and you can't see that by inspecting the command line.